# Get Switch State from specific cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I am working on a iOS app that has two `ViewControllers`. The first is a `TableView` which creates a row for each index in a array. Each cell of this `TableView` shows the content in the array corresponding to the index and has a switch. The second `ViewController` has an image and a label and they are supposed to change depending the switch state. So, how can I get the switch state from a specific cell?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var state_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descr_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myimg: UIImageView!
let arr: [String] = ["Text1","Text2", "Text3", "Text4"]

var switch_isOn = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(switch_isOn == false){
        myimg?.image = UIImage(named: "img1")
    }else{
        myimg?.image = UIImage(named: "img2")
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]

    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

    mySwitch.tag = 1001

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let segueIdentifier: String
    segueIdentifier = "segue"

    // Get the selected Cell and Iterate through it's subviews to find the switch using the tag
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    //Get the Cell Text
    print("\(cell?.textLabel?.text ?? "")")

    // Iterate through subviews of Cell
    for v in cell?.subviews ?? [] {

        // If a view found with tag == 1001 then it's the switch view because we had assigned 1001 to the switch view
        if v.tag == 1001 {

            // One last check we cast the view to UISwitch if it succeed then it's the switch view
            if let mySwitch = v as? UISwitch {

                if(mySwitch.isOn == true){
                    descr_label?.text = "\(cell?.textLabel?.text ?? "")"
                    print("The cell has the Switch On")
                    switch_isOn = true
                }else{
                    descr_label?.text = "\(cell?.textLabel?.text ?? "")"
                    switch_isOn = false
                    print("The cell has the Switch Off")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

}

Comment: I assume you can just get a cellForRowAtIndexPath using index of the cell you need the value for and from that cell get your switch and check it's value?

Comment: As a more elegant option you might create a struct MyStruct(yourStringValue,switchSate)...and make the source array of these structs. Every time you flip the switch you update the value of your source...so later for your second controller you can just use that source array without talking to UI elements.

Answer (score 4):

Using the accessory view for the switch seems to be an easy solution but it's very cumbersome to access the view. Something like `for v in cell?.subviews ?? []` and dealing with tags is horrible.

A <strike>better</strike> more efficient solution is a custom cell class.

In Interface Builder set the style of the cell to `custom` and drag an `UILabel` and an `UISwitch` into the canvas. Set the class of the cell to `TableViewCell`.

Add a new CocoaTouch class `TableViewCell` as subclass of `UITableViewCell`. You need two IBOutlets, one IBAction and a `callback` variable. The callback is important to keep the state of the switch in the model. Connect the outlets and the action in IB.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var switcher : UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!

    var callback : ((Bool)->())?

    @IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch) {
        callback?(sender.isOn)
    }
}
```

Create a data source model containing the text and the state of the switch

```
struct Item {
    var text : String
    var isSelected : Bool 

    init(text : String, isSelected : Bool = false {
        self.text = text
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

Declare the data source array

```
var arr : [Item] = [Item(text: "Text1"), Item(text: "Text2"), Item(text: "Text3"), Item(text: "Text4")]
```

Replace `cellForRow` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let item = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = item.text
    cell.switcher.isOn = item.isSelected

    // the callback updates the model and is called when the value of the switch changes
    cell.callback = { newValue in
         item.isSelected = newValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

Replace `didSelectRow` with (yes, it's only one line, it passes the index path as `sender` parameter)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Finally Implement `prepare(for segue`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController // the class of the second view controller
        // get the current index path
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        let item = arr[indexPath.row]
        // get the state of the switch from the model, not from the view 
        let isSelected = item.isSelected
        // do something with `isSelected`  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think you could clean this up further by not exposing the cell's `IBOutlets`, having an item property on the cell, and maybe `func configure(item: Item, callback: Bool->())`

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want properly, you're going to want to set up a custom cell.

An example of this is below, and assumes a Storyboard/XIB UI:

```
import UIKit

class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentSwitch: UISwitch!

    // So that we can identify the cell in our table view controller.
    static let identifier: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

in order to use this with your table view. you will have to register the cell for use in `SwitchTableViewController.viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.register(SwitchTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SwitchTableViewCell.identifier)
```

Next, you're going to want to modify `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(SwitchTableViewCell.identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    // cell.contentSwitch will be setup as an outlet via Storyboard / XIB.
    return cell
}
```

after that's done, go ahead and add a variable to `SwitchTableViewController`:

`fileprivate var selectedState: UIControl.State?`

And update `didSelectRowAt` to store the state from the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SwitchTableViewCell
    selectedState = cell.contentSwitch.state
    segueIdentifier = "segue" // probably want a more meaningful segue name here.
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

finally, override `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ContentViewController { // cast accordingly, 'ContentViewController' is placeholder
            // pass the state to the destination view controller
            vc.state = selectedState
            selectedState = nil
        }
    }
}
```

and that's you done!

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to read the state of a switch from a cell. You can create a custom cell class and access that using IBOutlets and even you can use delegates to get back from the Custom Cell class back to your View Controller. If you're using this code for learning purposes it's Ok to use and add any types of Controls to the cell like this but in real project you might try Custom cells.

See the commented areas in the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myimg: UIImageView!
   var arr: [String] = ["bla", "blablabla", "blabla"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myimg?.image = UIImage(named: "Image1")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return arr.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->   UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default,
    reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    let mySwitch = UISwitch()

    // Add a tag to your switch so later on you can access the switch using this tag
    mySwitch.tag = 1001

    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     segueIdentifier = "segue"

     // Get the selected Cell and Iterate through it's subviews to find the switch using the tag
     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

     // Iterate through subviews of Cell
     for v in cell?.subviews ?? [] {

        // If a view found with tag == 1001 then it's the switch view because we had assigned 1001 to the switch view
        if v.tag == 1001 {

            // One last check we cast the view to UISwitch if it succeed then it's the switch view
            if let mySwitch = v as? UISwitch {

               // Here you can get the state of the switch
                let switchState = mySwitch.state

            }
        }
    }
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: self)
   }
}
```

As I said this is not the best way to add and read views using tags but still good to know that you can

**Edit:**

Here is the complete solution for your project to work. You already have a ViewController but you don't have a DetailViewController to which you want to segue

View Controller Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


let rooms: [String] = ["Kitchen","Living Room", "Master's Bedroom", "Guest's Bedroom"]
let segueIdentifier = "segueIdentifier"
var switch_isOn = false


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rooms.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = rooms[indexPath.row]

    let mySwitch = UISwitch()
    cell.accessoryView = mySwitch

    mySwitch.tag = 1001

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Get the selected Cell and Iterate through it's subviews to find the switch using the tag
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // Iterate through subviews of Cell
    for v in cell?.subviews ?? [] {

        // If a view found with tag == 1001 then it's the switch view because we had assigned 1001 to the switch view
        if v.tag == 1001 {
            // One last check we cast the view to UISwitch if it succeed then it's the switch view
            if let mySwitch = v as? UISwitch {
                // Assign the current state of the switch to switch_isOn variable
                self.switch_isOn = mySwitch.isOn
            }
        }
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier {
        if let detailViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            // used guard let to be on safe side
            guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }
            // pass in the data needs to the detail view controller
            detailViewController.descr = rooms[indexPath.row]
            detailViewController.isOn = switch_isOn
        }
    }
}
}
```

Detail View Controller Code

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var descr_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var state_label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

var descr = ""
var isOn = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    descr_label.text = descr
    // for UIImage you can use UIImage(named: "on_image") but i have used the imageLiteral which is pics directly the image from xcassets 
    myImageView.image = isOn ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "on_image") : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "off_image")
    state_label.text = isOn ? "Switch is ON" : "Switch is Off"

}

}
```

[Example Project download here](https://www.swiftyninja.com/project-master/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I got an "error". The switch state was always rawValue = 1 so I choose to make an if(mySwitch.isOn == true){myimg?.image = UIImage(named: "image1")}else{myimg?.image = UIImage(named: "image2")} but the images does not update. I have to do the same with a label (label_descrstate?.text = "Image1" or "Image2") but it does not work as well. The Image and the label are in a different ViewController (don't know if that changes anything). Any ideas?

Comment: a switch state is by default always On, you can set that to off or rawValue = 1 means it's On. try to set the switch state to of in cellForRow when you create your switch. Then you will get off by default. but it should be set always by your data model. By the way the code here only reads the state of the switch I don't know how you update your cells after state did changed

Comment: It's not the cell that has to update! It a second viewController. After selecting a cell it goes to this second ViewController . This second viewController is supposed to have image1 if the switch from the selected cell is off and image2 if the switch is on. I have also two labels. one to that's supposed to show the switch state (ON or OFF) and another that's supposed to say "The image at (cell text) is" but I can't update both labels and image. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: in that case you have problem with your segue and as I see you're not sending the right information to the nextView. try to see the prepareForSegue function that you pass in the right information i mean .on or .off i can see you're setting your segueIdentifier manually have you set that up in storyboards or not? or send a link to your project so I can see where you have the problem

Comment: I can go from one view controller to another so I guess the segue is correct. I have updated the code above so that you can check it out.

Comment: see my update I think you are not passing the information from one view to the next view

Comment: why do ``let item = arr[indexPath.row]`` ?

Comment: Btw, the code does not work. Every time I select a cell in the app the Thread 1: Signal SIGABRIT error appears in the ``let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath``. Console: Could not cast value of type 'x.ViewController' to 'NSIndexPath'

Comment: That's an example you should have something like that in the class. **self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: indexPath)** now it will not crash change self to indexPath. once again if you want a working solution then you can share your example project so someone can edit and fix the problem you have

Comment: https://github.com/JoaoPimentao/Project Hope you have more luck than I had!

Comment: @JoaoPimentao see the updated section and download the project from there don't forget to mark the right answer so other visitors benefit from it

Comment: Using tags to identify subviews in a cell from the view controller is a terrible way to do this… that's one reason people end up with "massive view controllers". Creating a custom cell and object will make your life much simpler, and remove a lot of code from the view controller.

Comment: @AshleyMills if you have read my answer carefully the first thing I have mention is that it's not the best way but it's good to know there is this way still available. You have to read the answer carefully then try to down vote the answer

Comment: Giving someone an answer that you know is not a good way to do it just encourages poor practice. If you know there's a better solution, why not give that?

Comment: @AshleyMills The answer is not poor, I am not going to have a big argument with you here but once again i encourage you to read my whole answer **If you're using this code for learning purposes it's Ok to use and add any types of Controls to the cell like this but in real project you might try Custom cells**  I am clear enough some daylight if you're trying to learn the.....